# How to add both lower() and strip() in same loop

Tags: python

I'm a newbie but trying to learn fast.

Here is the code:

```
current_users = ['john', '    Bimu', 'admin              ', 'royo', 'AbCdEf', 'popo']

current_users = [current_users.strip() for current_users in current_users]

current_users = [current_users.lower() for current_users in current_users]

new_users = ['astra', '   JOHN', 'RoYO', ' gfgf', 'toui       ', '     popo']

new_users_stripped = new_users[:]

for new_user in new_users:

    if new_user.strip() not in current_users:

        print("Username " + new_user + " is available")

    else:

         print("Username " + new_user + " is already taken. You will need "
                "to chose another username")
```

I want to strip AND lower the data but want to show the original username back at the end. I'd also like to make my code cleaner. So far I've been able to strip() OR to lower(), but unable to do both. I still run in the problem that it seems to me it should run inside the loop but I don't know how.

Anybody can help? Thanks!

Comment: `[current_users.strip().lower() for current_users in current_users]` ... its not even worth an answer...

Comment: Literally just do exactly what your title says.

Comment: Thanks, it works! current_users.strip().lower() worked

Any way to make my code cleaner?

Answer (score 0):

I'd have `current_users` be a `set` to make searching it a little more efficient.

```
current_users = ['john', '    Bimu', 'admin              ', 'royo', 'AbCdEf', 'popo']

current_users = set(user.strip().lower() for user in current_users)

new_users = ['astra', '   JOHN', 'RoYO', ' gfgf', 'toui       ', '     popo']

for user in new_users:
    if user.strip().lower() in current_users:
        print("Username {} is available".format(user))
    else:
        print("Username {} is not available".format(user))
```

Here we don't save the result of `user.strip().lower()`, so the old value is still stored in `user`

Comment: Thanks! I didn't use "set" yet (not there in my learning), but I'll take a look. Why do you think it would be more efficient?

Comment: It really only matters for large collections, but when you do something like `if item in list` Python will go through the list in order to try and find `item`.  So if you have a million item list python has to do a million comparisons to find the last item. `set`s work by hashing the items.  Basically, it does some math to assign every item a group.  Then when you ask the `set` if it contains a certain item, it only has to look in that specific bucket, drastically reducing the time it takes to find items.  They do take up more space than `list`s and they do not preserve the order of the items.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the information. So if I understand correctly, the "set" here would be user and it would allow Python to look for user only instead of scanning everything?

Answer (score -4):

If you want to keep the original, then you should make a copy of the original and make modifications only to the copy. That way you have both the original and a modified username.

Comment: current_users.strip().lower() solved my problem... But my code still look lousy...